# Code throws "End if without block If" when attempting to compile. (If statement used for nested loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Attempting to prompt excel to move into another nested loop should one of my variables become greater then a given value. However, when attempting to compile, I receive the "End If without block If" error.

I've attempted to place a "Endif" after the "next m", but with no success. I've tried a few other workarounds that don't use "if"; however, a if-statement seems inevitable with the code I am trying to write.

```
For i = 1 To 4000000

    r = x + y
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Z, 1).Value = r
    Z = Z + 1


    x = r + y
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Z, 1).Value = x
    Z = Z + 1


    y = r + x
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Z, 1).Value = y
    Z = Z + 1

    If Z > 499 Then For m = 1 To 501

        e = 1

        d = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(e, 1).Value Mod 2
        If d = 1 Then Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(e, 1).ClearContents

        e = e + 1

        If e > 500 Then Range(q, 1) = "=Sum(A1:A500)" And Z = 1 And q = q + 1

    Next m
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: You can't do `If Z > 499 Then For m = 1 To 501`. Put the `For` loop definition on its own line.

Comment: I think you should google how `If...End If` and `For...Next` statements work in VBA. This part is wrong: `If Z > 499 Then For m = 1 To 501` among others

Comment: Also where did `x` and `y` come from? I think you did not post the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after typing the `Then` keyword, then you don't have an `If...End If` block, but an `If` *statement* - like this:

```
If True Then DoSomethingConditional
```

Where `DoSomethingConditional` can be many things... but not a `For...Next` *block*!

Change it to an `If...End If` block:

```
If True Then
    DoSomethingConditional
End If
```

Now `DoSomethingConditional` can be anything you want:

```
If Z > 499 Then
    For m = 1 To 501
        '...
    Next
End If
```

Notice how [consistent indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) makes it plain obvious where a block starts, where it ends, what's inside it and how deeply nested that is.

Rule of thumb, avoiding `If` *statements* and consistently using properly indented `If...End If` *blocks* is a good idea, for both consistency and maintainability (in curly-braces languages this is analoguous to consistently putting the braces around conditional scopes, even if it's just one statement and the braces are optional).

This means this instruction: `If d = 1 Then Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(e, 1).ClearContents` becomes:

```
If d = 1 Then 
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(e, 1).ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: This was an incredibly helpful answer. Constructive criticism associated with best practices is appreciated immensely. This did solve my original issue. Still learning the ropes and I appreciate the solid guidance